# JavaScript in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7

I am creating a Windows 7.1 Phone app where I am using webbrowser to display an ePUB book. I want to add to this html file a JavaScript script and  to know how to enable JavaScript in the browser object in my app? I have set the `IsScriptEnabled` property to true but that does not seem to help.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can add js code to html page:

Xaml file

```
 <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsScriptEnabled="True" ScriptNotify="webBrowser_ScriptNotify"/>
```

Cs file

```
private void scrollTo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string H = y.Text;
        webBrowser.InvokeScript("scroll", H);
    }

    private void getscroll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.InvokeScript("getScroll");
    }

    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(TitleContainer.OpenStream("page.html"));
            string content = "<script language=\"JavaScript\">"
                + "function scroll(H)"
                + "{"
                + "window.scrollTo(0, H);"
                + "}"
                + "function getScroll()"
                + "{"
                + "var body = document.body;"
                + "var docElem = document.documentElement;"
                + "var Y = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;"
                + "window.external.Notify(\"\"+Y);"
                + "}"
                + "</script>"
                + reader.ReadToEnd();
            webBrowser.NavigateToString(content);
    }

    private void webBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        y.Text = e.Value;
    }
```

Original article with source code [here](http://wp7rocks.com/posts/details/2550) (in Russian)

Comment: it is a helpful link thank you but the big issue for me it is how i can add a script javascript to my html file which has been already displayed in my browser like this wpf  you can add a script using var doc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser2.Document;
            var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<HTMLHeadElement>().First();